# How to automatically update Google Calendar from shared csv file

Tags: calendar, csv, google-calendar

I am creating a regular snapshot csv file from a proprietary calendar program. The CSV file is formatted so that it can be imported into Google Calendar.

I'm wondering if there is a way to put this file somewhere and subscribe to it in Google Calendar or a better way to have Google Calendar update itself on a regular basis, so that it reflects the latest version of the snapshot file.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: This would require writting a program to parse the file and modify the account using the Google Calendar API.

Comment: Do you have access to PHP or know how to programming in it?  The Google Calendar API can be access with a couple different languages

Comment: I would prefer to create the appropriate file on my windows PC and store it on something like Dropbox where Google Calendar can subscribe to it. It appears that one option would be to create an ics file and subscribe to that, but it seems to require more work to create that file.

Comment: What about Flow/IFTTT/etc.?

Answer (score 0):

[Quoted from this official Google Document](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/)

The Google Calendar API lets you develop client applications that create new events, edit or delete existing events, and search for events. This document describes how to use RESTful calling style and client libraries for various programming languages (**currently Java, Python, PHP, .NET and Ruby**) to access and edit Google Calendar data.